# What is the default WordPress API

Tags: wordpress, api

I'm looking to start a new WordPress API based project. I want to make sure I'm starting with the best tools at hand so that I'm not changing my mind half way through. What I want to know is; What is the best supported API framework for WordPress? What is the default API that comes as part of WordPress core and how does it compare to other WP API plugins.

I'm leaning towards the WP REST API however I would like to know if the XML-RPC interface 'WordPress API' would alternatively be the right way to go.

Any feedback would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *official* wordpress API is still under ongoing development. You can find the old legacy REST api here, which will work, but might be broken in the future: http://wp-api.org/index-deprecated.html

As for the new and improved version 2 found here http://v2.wp-api.org/ this is the version that will be supported and used in the future. **I would recommend using this API**, as there will most likely not be any huge breaking changes in the future, and this is being actively maintained and developed by a considerable amount of contributors.

There's still a lot missing from the official API, but they're working away on these issues as we speak. In it's current state, it's still quite powerful.

Comment: Thank @Tennyson that was right on track with what I was looking for. I will likely use 'WordPress REST API Version 2' as recommended.

Answer (score 0):

By default WordPress come with [REST-API](http://v2.wp-api.org/). If you don't want to use WordPress REST-API then You can use API-Framework and access the wordpress functions.

There are small api framework like [slim api framework](https://www.slimframework.com/), [fat-free api framework](https://fatfreeframework.com) you can use for API's.